# Dealing with social syntactic sugar

Tags: discussion, edits, signatures

I just stumbled upon a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577373/css-issue-responsive-centering-not-working) starting with

> Hello friendly SO ppl,
>   I am more or less a CSS noob; and for the life of me, I can't solve this issue. Hopefully this will be easy for one of you awesome people.

and ending with

> Thanks a bunch for your help.

While I do not consider this a big issue, I often see phrases like the above which do not really add anything to the question - is it okay to edit them away?

---

By the way: The above really just was a random example.

Answer (score 7):

From [What kind of behavior do we expect from our users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):

> **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

While it may seem subtle, these things actually hamper the community's ability to quickly and efficiently navigate the system in search of interesting questions to answer.

First, greetings make it harder for users viewing the main page from seeing the question preview. Thus, they must click on the link in order to see anything useful. If you see greetings, please edit them out.

Second, closing phrases and tag lines, while they may not seem long, take up vertical space on the screen.  Since many of these are inserted on their own line, with a space above and below, this pushes more of the content in answers down off the screen.  People landing on the page from Google searches already see advertisements, which take up space. Signatures, tag lines, and closing phrases are just additional noise that people looking for answers don't want to see. If you see these, please edit them out as well.

In addition, if you see other problems with the post, fix those as well. This creates the best content possible, void of any distractions or noise, focusing on the core content itself. <strike>Hope this helps.</strike>

**NOTE:** I generally try to sneak syntactic sugar in my last paragraph, so it's less likely to take up vertical space on the screen, such as the "Hope this helps" in the last paragraph. User [Thursday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/thursday) points out that this can still affect people on very small devices, such as a mobile phone. Thus, it's probably best that we edit these out as well.

Comment: Isn't "Hope this helps" also noise? Absent evidence to the contrary, one naturally assume that an answer is posted in good faith, i.e., with the intent of it being helpful.

Comment: @Thursday. Ah, good eye! I was hoping someone would catch that. This is a little trick I keep up my sleeve. If you're going to say "thanks" or some brief similar closing, such as "good luck" or "hope this helps", etc, at least put it on the same line as the rest of your text. That way it doesn't take up vertical space on the screen when people scroll through the content. I do sometimes edit those out, but they're not as high priority to me as something that actually pushes other content down. Hope this helps clarify. :)

Comment: It does take up vertical space on my phone's screen...

Comment: @Thursday - Hmmm, I guess I never thought about that before. I rarely use my mobile phone for Stack Exchange. Ironically, I don't use it because -- you'll laugh at this -- the screen is too small. :) I'll expand/update my answer, as I think that's a good point!